# How to catch a python warning error and 'bury' it?

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, error-handling, gdal

We're running a script in which we use a specific module that calls another module. To be more specific, our script uses a module named "rasterstats" that calls the GDAL module.

All of the script works fine but for some reason, we're getting a "Warning" error in the console. The warning is not critic because the module assumes something out of it (it assumes the right thing).

The warning is: `"Warning 1: Failed to fetch spatial reference on layer out to build transformer, assuming matching coordinate systems."`

In our script, we use the `raster_stats` command, which calls the `gdal.RasterizeLayer`. The warning can be find in this file if you search for `failed to fetch spatial reference`: http://worldwind31.arc.nasa.gov/svn/trunk/GDAL/GDAL-1.7.2/alg/gdalrasterize.cpp

So my question is: considering that the warning isn't critic and the script works perfectly, is it possible to catch the warning and bury it so that it doesn't show in the console ?

Comment: Hi, if my answer works for you, kindly mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Though it is best to eliminate causes of warnings rather than suppressing them, you can hide them by [running with -W](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W).

For example, `python -W ignore file.py`